# How do I increase the width and font-size of my twitter feed widget?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I have created a pure JS twitter feed widget, however, I cannot figure out how to increase the width of the feed to 960 pixels and bump up the font size.

I have done a couple of google searches which suggested of adding some css to target and increase the size of the iframe

```
#twitter-widget-0{width:960px;} /*this does not work*/
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdhux5ff/) of my working feed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to fixing the width:

in the css I added:

```
iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']{ width:100% !important;}
```